# Получаю ошибку при переадресации, после успешной авторизации

Tags: php

`Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by` Ошибка при переадресации, после успешной авторизации

```
<?php
include "header.html";
require "db.php";
    $data=$_POST;
    if(isset($data['do_login']))
    {
        $errors = array();
        $user = R::findOne('users', 'login = ?', array($data['login']));
        if( $user)
        {
            if(password_verify($data['password'], $user->password))
            {
                // $_SESSION['logged_user'] = $user;
                header('Refresh: 5; Location: mainwindow.html');
                echo '<div style = "color: green;">Вы Авторизованы! <br/> Можете перейти на <a href="http://localhost/mainwindow.php">главную</a> страницу!</div><hr>';

                // exit;
            } else {
                $errors[] = 'Пароль неправильно введен';
            }
        } else
        {
            $errors[] = 'Пользователь не найден!';
        }
        if (!empty($errors)) {
            echo'<div style="color:red;">'.array_shift($errors).'</div><hr>';
        } 
    }
?>
    <head>
    <link href = "autorizstyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
    <body>
<div class="box">
    <div>
        <p class="titleaut">Авторизация</p>
    <form action="login.php" method="POST">
    <div class="win_log">    
    <p>
            <p><strong>Логин:</strong></p>  
            <input type="text" name="login" value = "<?php echo @$data['login'];?>">
        </p>
</div>
<div class="win_log">
        <p>
            <p><strong>Пароль:</strong></p> 
            <input type="password" name="password" value = "<?php echo @$data['password'];?>">
        </p>
</div>
        <p>
            <button class="buton" type="submit" name = "do_login">Войти</button>
        </p>

    </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

<?php
 include "footer.html";
?>
```

Как звучит ошибка:

```
 Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\OpenServerPanel\OSPanel\domains\localhost\header.html:1) in C:\OpenServerPanel\OSPanel\domains\localhost\login.php on line 14
```

Код header.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href = "stylemain.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="mainers__div">
            <a href="/mainwindow.php" class="mainers">Главная</a>
            </div>
            <div class="autlog">
            <a href="/login.php">Авторизация</a>
            <a href="/signup.php">Регистрация</a>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: вам там вроде черным по белому советуют, что не надо пытаться выставлять заголовки, после того как вы отправили контент (начали отправлять)

Comment: не могу понять, что в понимании php заголовки, я его учу всего лишь 2 день, так что не судите строго.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Помните, что функцию `header()` можно вызывать только если клиенту еще
>   не передавались данные. То есть она должна идти первой в выводе, перед
>   ее вызовом не должно быть никаких HTML-тегов, пустых строк и т.п.

см. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php

--> Вы вызываете при работе `header('Refresh: 5; Location: mainwindow.html');`, а перед тем выводите содержимое `header.html`

Тут решение такое может быть - помещайте нужное в переменные, заместо `echo` и потом выводите, где нужно, в соответствии с очередностью.

Тогда Вам не нужно вставлять содержимое файла перед кодом `php` - пишите обычным порядком `html`, а `php` вставляете выше `<!DOCTYPE html>`

И разберитесь с кодом - что у Вас дублируются `<head>` и `<body>`? - Уберите лишние, сделайте нормальную валидную страницу `html`, а код `php` выше, как уже описано.

Comment: каким же тупым я себя чувствую, понимая, что прочитал раз 10 про хедер, а ошибка была наиглупейшая)

Comment: Не расстраивайтесь - если код сразу работает - значит, что-то в нем не то)